# Can I use 14/2 cable for a light switch loop?

Tags: electrical

Can I use 14/2 wire to feed switch leg on 1 light? The light will be on separate breaker.It is just a can light with 60 watt bulb.

Answer (score 1):

You can use cable that contains 14AWG conductors for adding an additional light on the circuit as long as the circuit breaker that protects that wiring circuit is not rated above 15A.

It there is a case where the existing wiring of that circuit happens to be 12AWG and the breaker is rated at 20A then any additional wiring runs you add to that circuit will have to be 12AWG as per code and safety guidelines. A 20A breaker cannot properly protect a wiring circuit that contains any 14AWG wires that may develop a short circuit or be exposed to an overload.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't.  **You have to use /3 cable on a switch leg.**   Using /2 has been outlawed since at least 2011.

So now neutral is down at the switch.  Sooner or later, you or the next owner [becomes **this guy**](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/152802/can-i-add-a-receptacle-from-a-bath-fan-switch-box) from 7 hours ago.  Who wants to extend a receptacle off a switch loop.  And like him, you say "Thank you, thank you NEC for making somebody install that neutral years ago".    Just one problem: now that 14/3 is carrying receptacle loads, and it isn't just 1 amp anymore.

So no on the #14.  We don't build systems only for ideal conditions.